# macOS: Create .app bundle

Tags: java, macos, app-bundle

I am currently developing a `Java` application. Now I created a setup for Windows users to make it easier for them to use the application. Now I would like to do the same (or let's say the equivalent) for `macOS` users. As I am not a macOS user I started to do some research about this and came up with the `.app-bundles` which seem to be a good way to achieve my goal (is this correct, or are there betters ways to ease to first usage of the application without using the Apple Store?).

Now I am wondering how to create these bundles - is this possible on pure `Unix` as well or do I need to use `macOS` to do so? And how exactly do I create them?

Edit: Or is it a better way to use the [`appbundler`](https://java.net/projects/appbundler)?
Currently the usage of [`packr`](https://github.com/libgdx/packr) seems to be a good way for me, but I am not sure, if it is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS you can have something called document bundles. They appear as a single file in the finder, but they are really folders which can contain any files you want to put in there. Inside your Java app you would treat the bundle just a like a directory.

See the apple documentation for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#